# How to move third element in block down with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How move third element down, that first block with logo, and second other full width contain another panel,and down will be another panel?
this block (pastenow.ru/57IX6) need to move and it must be like this : pastenow.ru/57IXE

```
<nav class="navbar">

<!--start of top_panel-->
<div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""> </div>

<div class="panel"> 
    <div class="nav_title">С нами ловят все!</div>
    <div class="phone">8 800 553535</div>
    <div class="address_wrapper">
        <div class="address">Павлодар, ул. Мира 7</div>
        <div class="address">Павлодар, ул. Мира 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="call_btn def_btn">Заказать звонок</div>
</div>
<!--end of top_panel-->
<!--start of bottom_panel-->
<div class="bottom_panel">
    <div class="main">Главная</div>
    <div class="about_us">компании</div>
    <div class="tournament">Турниры</div>
    <div class="goods">Товары</div>
    <div class="news">Новости</div>
    <div class="photo">Фото</div>
    <div class="video">Видео</div>
    <div class="contact">Контакты</div>
    <div class="social_icons_wrapper">
        <div ><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube icon_size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div ><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram icon_size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div ><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-vk icon_size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div ><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp icon_size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-telegram icon_size" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end of bottom_panel-->
```

if add flex-wrap: wrap; so all goes down, but i need only one.

css

```
.container{
    width: 1170px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Museo Cyrl 900";
}

.header_line{
    width: 100%;
    height: 122px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo{
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
}

.panel{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.bootom_panel{
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a codepen demo with slight adjustments in the layout which you have provided. Please click on this link: https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/qwbXLm?editors=1100

Major change here is I have wrapped upper panel and lower panel in one wrapper and then gave them respective properties.

```
<div class="panel-wrap">
  <div class="panel"></div>
  <div class="bottom_panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i love you man, can you share, your knowledge? where did you learn it?I hung over the menu layout for 7 hours, without having made it, please share the resources on which you taught css and flexbox, thank you very much.

Comment: my mistake was, that i make display:inline-flex; i so have many times make wrapper for that panels))

Comment: Hey! glad to know that it resolved your issue. You can up-vote the answer if it is of your help. Here is a good resource to learn about flex-box: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/